# Android device (4.1) doesn't scroll wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-sdk-2.3

The wallpaper in Galaxy S III (android 4.1) device doesn't scroll (panning). Scrolling occurs as expected with Galaxy S II (android 2.3) device. I'm using the following code:

```
    wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Is there an option to make the wallpaper be same (scroll or not) in both devices?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's default Touchwiz 3.0 launcher breaks scrolling, a feature Android has had for a *long* time. The only way to solve this is to switch to a different launcher/homescreen app, for example, Apex or Nova. This, combined with the ridiculous switching around of mount points in the internal and external SD cards, has turned me off of Samsung Android devices. Permanently.

Comment: 3rd party launchers apparently use the same engine (except golauncher) and will not scroll either. I suspect there's a licensing issue involved.